# Laravel 5 - Handling form data which include multiple file uploads

Tags: forms, laravel-5

I am trying to work out the best way to do something.  I have a form with a lot of fields, including a file input which allows multiple files to be uploaded.

All of this is linked to the model/form `ReportingDoc`

```
{!! Form::model(new App\ReportingDoc, [
    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    'route' => ['projects.reportingDoc.store', $project->id],
    'files' => true
]) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('workType', 'Work Type:', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label blue')) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="workType" name="workType">
            <option value="recurring">Recurring</option>
            <option value="adHoc">Ad-hoc</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

//Lots of other inputs

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('filePath', 'Supporting Documents:', array('class' => 'col-md-5 control-label green')) !!}
    <div class="col-md-7">
        {!! Form::file('filePath[]', array('multiple'=>true)) !!}
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Save Data', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The model looks like the following:

```
class ReportingDoc extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reporting_doc';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'projectId');
    }
}
```

So the model belongs to a Project.  At the moment, the migration looks like the following:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reporting_doc', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->String('workType')->default('');
        //all my other inputs
        $table->String('filePath')->default('');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('reporting_doc', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('projectId')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->foreign('projectId')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

In the controller for this route, I have my store method. At the moment it looks like the following:

```
public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $workType = Input::get('workType');
    //Other inputs
    $projectId = $project->id;

    $reportingDoc = new ReportingDoc();
    $reportingDoc->workType = $workType;
    //Other inputs
    $reportingDoc->projectId = $projectId;
    $dsReportingDoc->save();

    return Redirect::route('projects.reportingDoc.create', $project->id)
        ->with('message', 'Files uploaded.');

    /* Old part
    $files = Input::file('filePath');
    $file_count = count($files);
    $uploadcount = 0;

    if(isset($files)) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $destinationPath = public_path() .'/uploads/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $uploadcount ++;
        }
    }

    if($uploadcount == $file_count){
        Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully');

        return Redirect::route('projects.reportingDoc.create', $project->id)
            ->with('message', 'Files uploaded.');
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::route('projects.reportingDoc.create', $project->id)
            ->with('message', 'Something went wrong - Please try again.');
    }
    */
}
```

As you can see, I have commented out the file part for now.  What I was going to do was get the paths for all the uploaded files, and serialize them into
one field in the database - filePath.

However, to me this seems very messy.  I would imagine it is best to have something like an uploads table which is linked to this model.  I can then create an uploads object for each file that is uploaded.

One thing I am confused about is the form, and it being linked to my `ReportingDoc` Model.  With this new approach, would I need to link it somehow to both models? `ReportingDoc` and `Uploads`?

Really, I am just looking for advice and guidance on the best way to achieve what I am after.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already almost done. The best way to do what you're trying to achieve is to create a `ReportingDocUpload` model which *belongs to* `ReportingDoc`, then remove the filePath field from Reporting Doc.

Your model should look like: `class ReportingDocUpload { ... protected $fillable = ['filepath', 'reportingdoc_id']; ... }`

Then to save your files, do this:

```
if($file_count) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $destinationPath = public_path() .'/uploads/';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $rUpload = ReportingDocUpload::create(['filepath' => $filename, 'reportingdoc_id' => $reportingDoc->id]);
        $uploadcount ++;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to delete files from disk when the entry is deleted...

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    //delete associated file
    static::deleting(function($docUpload){
        try{
            $filepath = public_path('uploads/').$docUpload->filepath;
            if(file_exists($filepath))
            {
                unlink($filepath);
            }
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            //some error while deleteing
            \Log::info('Error deleting: '.$filepath);
            \Log::debug($e);
        }
    });
}
```

Cheers..